# Get a sub array with a pattern in php

Tags: php, arrays

Consider this array in PHP:

```
$list = array('apple','orange','alpha','bib','son','green','odd','soap');
```

How can i get a sub array of elements start with letter 'a' or 's' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

```
$items = preg_grep('~^[as]~', $list);
```

Comment: $a = preg_grep('#^a|s#', array_map('strtolower',  $list)); Just in case you have mixed case (make apple Apple in your test). +1 for posting a proper PHP array we can just copy and use. Thoughtful.

Comment: Ah, well it seems to, then again this is better $a = preg_grep('#^a|s#i',  $list); <-use the i regex switch

Answer (score 4):

Check out `array_filter` here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
$list = array_filter($list, function ($a) { return $a[0] == 'a' || $a[0] == 's'; });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sublist = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    if ($list[$i][0] == 'a' or $list[$i][0] == 's') {
        $sublist[] = $list[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: $list[$i][0] <-- can you do that in PHP? =O Never thought of that one before... =] Nice! =]

Comment: @benqus: Yes, PHP allows you to give a string offset using the array-offset notation. Like any PHP operation involving strings, it won't behave well if you have a string in a multi-byte character set.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i =0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    if (substr($list[i], 1) == "a" || substr($list[i], 1) == "s") {
        //put it in an other array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

$list = array('apple','orange','alpha','bib','son','green','odd','soap');

$tmp_arr = array();
foreach ($list as $t)
{
    if (substr($t, 0, 1) == 'a' || substr($t, 0, 1) == 's')
    {
       $tmp_arr[] = $t;
    }
}

print_r($tmp_arr);

?>

//output: Array ( [0] => apple [1] => alpha [2] => son [3] => soap )

Comment: This poorly formatted answer is missing its explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

```
    $list = array('apple','orange','alpha','bib','son','green','odd','soap');


$a = array();
$s = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++)
{
    if (substr($list[$i], 0, 1) == "s")
    {
        $s[$i] = $list[$i];
    }
    else if (substr($list[$i], 0, 1) == "a")
    {
        $a[$i] = $list[$i];
    }
}
```